# Docker magento error

Tags: magento

I try to install magento via docker and i got errors. I follow this tutorial

https://github.com/andreaskoch/dockerized-magento

WARNING: Image for service installer was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use docker-compose build or docker-compose up --build.
    Creating dockerizedmagento_mysql_1
    Creating dockerizedmagento_fullpagecache_1
    Creating dockerizedmagento_sessions_1
    Creating dockerizedmagento_cache_1
    Creating dockerizedmagento_solr_1
    Creating dockerizedmagento_php_1
    Creating dockerizedmagento_nginx_1

```
ERROR: for nginx driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockerizedmagento_nginx_1 (f4231c1e80b680a8a59961cb3658c55d2b64cc3a3e980e09f8b94531a608892f): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: listen: address already in use
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 3, in 
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 63, in main
AttributeError: 'ProjectError' object has no attribute 'msg'
docker-compose returned -1
caner@vegan:~/magento-caner/dockerized-magento$ ./magento start
dockerizedmagento_fullpagecache_1 is up-to-date
dockerizedmagento_solr_1 is up-to-date
dockerizedmagento_mysql_1 is up-to-date
dockerizedmagento_sessions_1 is up-to-date
dockerizedmagento_cache_1 is up-to-date
dockerizedmagento_php_1 is up-to-date
Starting dockerizedmagento_nginx_1

ERROR: for nginx driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockerizedmagento_nginx_1 (3e4887cb50ff899b19f660d3886f03d6682cf6332373912c0aa9e3932f4d8e5c): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: listen: address already in use
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 3, in 
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 63, in main
AttributeError: 'ProjectError' object has no attribute 'msg'
docker-compose returned -1
caner@vegan:~/magento-caner/dockerized-magento$
```

after a whihle, the error is when i open the page

```
403 Forbidden

nginx/1.11.3
```

which are given from console :

```
installer_1 | 
installer_1 | Fixing filesystem permissions
installer_1 | Installation fininished
installer_1 | Frontend: http://dockerized-magento.local/
installer_1 | Backend: http://dockerized-magento.local/admin
installer_1 | - Username: admin
installer_1 | - Password: password123
```

images are

```
fabf508632a6 dockerizedmagentomaster_installer "/bin/install.sh" 4 minutes ago Up 4 minutes dockerizedmagentomaster_installer_1
44a8db375577 nginx:latest "nginx -g 'daemon off" 4 minutes ago Up 4 minutes 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp dockerizedmagentomaster_nginx_1
73883d1ad863 dockerizedmagentomaster_php "php-fpm" 4 minutes ago Up 4 minutes 9000/tcp dockerizedmagentomaster_php_1
6c7e24a5f1b6 dockerizedmagentomaster_solr "/usr/bin/java -Xmx10" 4 minutes ago Up 4 minutes 8983/tcp dockerizedmagentomaster_solr_1
824765d3e79d mysql:5.5 "docker-entrypoint.sh" 4 minutes ago Up 4 minutes 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp dockerizedmagentomaster_mysql_1
515fde576688 redis:latest "docker-entrypoint.sh" 28 minutes ago Up 4 minutes 6379/tcp dockerizedmagentomaster_sessions_1
e6a583fda276 redis:latest "docker-entrypoint.sh" 28 minutes ago Up 4 minutes 6379/tcp dockerizedmagentomaster_cache_1
e449459d1355 redis:latest "docker-entrypoint.sh" 28 minutes ago Up 4 minutes 6379/tcp dockerizedmagentomaster_fullpagecache_1
```

Also

```
[RuntimeException]

installer_1 | Magento folder could not be detected

installer_1 |
```

Also i tried with my env and yml:

yml

```
web:
  image: alexcheng/magento
  ports:
    - "8081:80"
  links:
    - mysql
  env_file:
    - env
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.6.23
  env_file:
    - env
  ports:
    - "3306:3306
```

env

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=magento
MYSQL_USER=magento
MYSQL_PASSWORD=magento
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=magento
MAGENTO_ADMIN_FIRSTNAME=Admin
MAGENTO_ADMIN_LASTNAME=MyStore
MAGENTO_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@example.com
MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD=magentorocks1
```

this time when i go to

http://localhost:8081/

it forwards me to

http://localhost:8081/index.php/install/wizard/config/

so that i can start installation wizard bt at that time, it doesno accept my username or another fields.

It says database connection error.

Comment: As a shot in the dark - if you kill all the running containers and then run ./magneto start does that work? Probably worth raising a github issue?

Comment: I restarted a lot of times.but still same